# Plyer "NotImplementedError: No usable implementation found!" while sending notifications in a .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a python script that should send a notifications when the code is finished or when the code has an error.
Here is the code:

```
from plyer import notification

try:
#code here

    notification.notify(title='Title', message=str(variable_name))
except Exception as e:
    notification.notify(title='Title', message=str(e))
```

When I run the script in PyCharm, it works, it sends the notification, but when I convert the script into a .exe file (using auto-py-to-exe) and run it, it gives me the `"NotImplementedError: No usable implementation found!"` error at the respective lines. (This errors show up in a pop up).

What am I doing wrong? Or should I change the way I send notifications in the file? If so, how?

Answer (score 6):

you gotta add this to the command that you're using to create the .exe file ( if you're using pyinstaller):
`--hidden-import plyer.platforms.win.notification`
for example, i ran this command to convert the script:
`pyinstaller -F -w script.py --hidden-import plyer.platforms.win.notification`
i was having the same error, then i fixed it with this.