# Python notification not working after compiling

Tags: python

My app is doing something weird. When the app sends a notification, it works just fine in the source code when its run with vs code. But after compiling with pyinstaller, suddenly it doesn't work.

code:

```
import plyer
notification.notify(title = 'Message', message = Message, app_icon = 'Ringer-Icon.ico', timeout = 10,)
```

After testing a separate file with this i go this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plyer\utils.py", line 93, in _ensure_obj
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plyer.platforms'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "notification test.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "plyer\facades\notification.py", line 79, in notify
  File "plyer\facades\notification.py", line 88, in _notify
NotImplementedError: No usable implementation found!
[12520] Failed to execute script 'notification test' due to unhandled exception!
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with plyer library of python when creating a executable using pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56281839/issue-with-plyer-library-of-python-when-creating-a-executable-using-pyinstaller)

Answer (score 0):

This question was already answered:

- [Issue with plyer library of python when creating a executable using pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56281839/issue-with-plyer-library-of-python-when-creating-a-executable-using-pyinstaller)
- [Plyer "NotImplementedError: No usable implementation found!" while sending notifications in a .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68614527/plyer-notimplementederror-no-usable-implementation-found-while-sending-notif)

You can specify the platform-dependent dependency(s) as [`--hidden-import`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html?highlight=Hidden#listing-hidden-imports) when packaging with PyInstaller.

E.g. for the [windows implementation](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/master/plyer/platforms/win/notification.py) use:

```
--hidden-import plyer.platforms.win.notification
```

Plyer supports *notifications* (with implementations) on following platforms except iOS (their namespace/folder name in parentheses):

- Android (`android`)
- Windows (`win`)
- OS X (`macosx`)
- Linux (`linux`)

See also:

- [Using PyInstaller to Easily Distribute Python Applications – Real Python](https://realpython.com/pyinstaller-python/)